# Long boot time with Ubuntu 16.04 & mounting and checking partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I have an ASUS laptop (i7 5500U, 8 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD) which takes quite long to boot Ubuntu 16.04 (+30s). I'm dual booting with Windows 10, which was preinstalled when it was bought. Recently, I installed 16.04 on another laptop in a similar set-up and I have the same feeling that it takes longer than it should. I have an old desktop pc that takes less time to boot ubuntu 16.04.

The output of `systemd-analyze blame` is the following (just look at the first five entries):

```
  9.152s dev-sda6.device
  5.908s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-feee34bb\x2df3a8\x2d4ce6\x2d93d5\x2df22a01f95edf.service
  5.904s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7876ae4d\x2da1e6\x2d413f\x2da917\x2d6f01418c255e.service
  4.424s click-system-hooks.service
  4.060s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-587F\x2d9A36.service
  3.350s boot-efi.mount
  2.845s NetworkManager.service
  2.552s gpu-manager.service
  2.314s thermald.service
  2.238s ModemManager.service
  2.225s accounts-daemon.service
  1.999s systemd-udevd.service
  1.251s keyboard-setup.service
   999ms rsyslog.service
   988ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   953ms grub-common.service
   842ms udisks2.service
   832ms polkitd.service
   692ms irqbalance.service
   677ms systemd-modules-load.service
   637ms systemd-journald.service
   612ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
   568ms apparmor.service
   564ms dev-sda7.swap
   505ms systemd-rfkill.service
   454ms rc-local.service
   370ms dev-hugepages.mount
   370ms colord.service
   366ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
   363ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
   348ms user@1000.service
   348ms systemd-sysctl.service
   321ms apport.service
   291ms home.mount
   290ms networking.service
   286ms ufw.service
   258ms systemd-random-seed.service
   242ms ondemand.service
   240ms speech-dispatcher.service
   235ms console-setup.service
   228ms lightdm.service
   226ms pppd-dns.service
   222ms snapd.autoimport.service
   221ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   206ms upower.service
   201ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   196ms wpa_supplicant.service
   185ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   185ms dev-mqueue.mount
   174ms systemd-journal-flush.service
   166ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   154ms avahi-daemon.service
   123ms systemd-logind.service
   122ms systemd-timesyncd.service
   110ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
   106ms setvtrgb.service
    97ms opt.mount
    51ms snapd.socket
    12ms alsa-restore.service
     7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
     6ms ureadahead-stop.service
     4ms dns-clean.service
     3ms resolvconf.service
     3ms systemd-user-sessions.service
     3ms rtkit-daemon.service
     2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
     1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

`/dev/sda6` is where Ubuntu is installed (100 GB, 10% used). The first `fsck` is done to a 600 GB partition (8% used), the second one to another 100 GB partition (26% used) and the third one to the `/boot/efi` partition of 100 MB. The HDD is mostly empty although mounting and checking seem to be taking most of the time to boot.

I guess I could disable the `fsck` done at startup, is this a good idea?
This is the file `/etc/fstab`:

```
`UUID=485c2bb5-53b5-421c-b826-284ce877b7ac /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=587F-9A36  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=feee34bb-f3a8-4ce6-93d5-f22a01f95edf /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /opt was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=7876ae4d-a1e6-413f-a917-6f01418c255e /opt            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=cc97a441-f71a-4cdd-99cb-a0f876b95f4d none            swap    sw              0       0`
```

What can I do to improve boot time?
Here's the output of `dmesg`:

```
...

[    1.946809] usb 1-8: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[    1.946810] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Generic
[    1.946812] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
[    1.950312] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtsx_usb
[    2.638502] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    2.880758] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    3.096061] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.126998] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[    4.127091] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    4.136656] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <FT-PC>.
[    5.935687] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    5.935760] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    5.935780] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    5.935833] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    5.935968] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    5.935985] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    5.936011] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    5.936028] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    5.936089] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    5.936142] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    5.936177] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    5.936182] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    5.936188] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[    5.936211] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    5.936225] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    5.936230] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    5.936235] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[    5.936256] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    5.950620] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[    5.951033] systemd[1]: Starting Set console keymap...
[    6.050548] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    6.050895] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    6.051218] systemd[1]: Started Read required files in advance.
[    6.052129] systemd[1]: Started Braille Device Support.
[    6.234547] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    6.235101] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    6.235605] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    6.235637] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    6.236000] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    6.237251] systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
[    6.401312] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    6.410560] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[    6.421407] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    6.421438] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    6.421454] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    6.635911] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    6.659893] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    6.728224] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[    6.738614] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    6.739163] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    6.740821] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    6.871636] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    9.638949] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    9.730314] systemd-journald[239]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   10.170525] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   10.380540] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   11.252286] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   11.252289] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   11.255367] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   11.258999] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:04:00.0 on minor 1
[   11.259003] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  340.98  Mon Sep 19 17:31:03 PDT 2016
[   11.334758] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   11.365793] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC3236: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   11.365797] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   11.365799] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   11.365801] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   11.365803] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[   11.365805] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x1b
[   11.411000] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input14
[   11.469965] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input15
[   11.470031] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input16
[   11.470091] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input17
[   11.491363] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[   11.491365] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[   11.557015] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4365 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
[   11.953441] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   11.953444] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   11.953446] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   11.953448] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[   11.953451] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
[   11.953455] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain dram locked by BIOS
[   13.149867] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   13.176251] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   13.366720] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam (04f2:b483)
[   13.409704] input: USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input18
[   13.409764] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   13.409765] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   13.641649] nvidia_uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 244
[   13.663023] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
[   13.682655] asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x1
[   13.682682] asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 7.9
[   13.682708] asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0xa0077
[   13.683322] input: Asus WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input19
[   13.684809] asus_wmi: Number of fans: 1
[   14.002442] wl 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   14.424638] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   14.424640] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   14.424641] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   14.424643] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.424645] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.424646] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.424647] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.424649] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   14.424650] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   14.424651] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.424652] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[   16.581361] Adding 15932412k swap on /dev/sda7.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:15932412k FS
[   22.928982] EXT4-fs (sda9): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   23.295728] EXT4-fs (sda8): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   23.857502] audit: type=1400 audit(1482223027.611:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=878 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.857510] audit: type=1400 audit(1482223027.611:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=878 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.857515] audit: type=1400 audit(1482223027.611:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=878 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.857520] audit: type=1400 audit(1482223027.611:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=878 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.857815] audit: type=1400 audit(1482223027.611:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=877 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.857822] audit: type=1400 audit(1482223027.611:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=877 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.858875] audit: type=1400 audit(1482223027.615:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=883 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.859020] audit: type=1400 audit(1482223027.615:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=882 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.859029] audit: type=1400 audit(1482223027.615:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=882 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.859974] audit: type=1400 audit(1482223027.615:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=885 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.519197] bbswitch: version 0.8
[   25.519203] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[   25.519207] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:04:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP
[   25.519214] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   25.519278] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[   25.519286] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:04:00.0 is on
[   26.126644] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   26.126684] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   26.126706] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   26.126726] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   26.126744] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   26.126763] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   26.126794] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   26.126813] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   26.142376] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   26.313515] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   26.316180] nvidia_uvm: Unregistered the UVM driver
[   26.337260] [drm] Module unloaded
[   26.355304] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[   26.355314] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   28.626111] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[   28.866165] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   28.869189] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   29.044820] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[   29.044882] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
```

Comment: Is 30s so slow ? What's the hurry ? I think sometimes you can get hung up on this quest for instant booting. The only way I know to noticeably speed up boot times is to use an SSD. Anyway, why not disable disk checking in fstab and see if that improves boot time, you can always run fsck manually if you need to. What was the reason for creating separate partition for ubuntu? I know many people do this but I have never got it myself.

Comment: I feel the total time between I turn on the computer and start working is ~ 1 min. +30 seconds to boot Ubuntu and then log into my account. After this, most programs take some seconds to load, although this happens only the first time they're loaded.  I just disabled fsck but it took the same time to boot up.
I have several partitions because I may have to resize the big one to make room for other users while the other ones will remain fixed with shared files.

Comment: So the problem isn't fsck then. What is the spin rate of your HDD ? Is it very full ? Are you using the Unity desktop ? I use XFCE on an SSD and I use legacy BIOS (not EUFI) and it is blazingly fast. Instead of using the defaults in fstab, change it to 'errors=remount-ro, relatime' and see if that speeds things up. (As default, file metadata is updated with access time for each file, relatime changes this to only update write time. You can go one step further and swap relatime for noatime, which doesn't update the access time at all).

Comment: Just fired up my system. Ignoring POST etc, so timing from the grub menu. 10 seconds to get to the login prompt, 4 seconds to login and have a working desktop. I put it all down to using an SSD and turning off access times.

Comment: If I remember correctly it is 7200 rpm; this laptop was bought a year ago. The HDD is almost empty (~ 10% used at most). I did the changes you said and it may feel a little bit faster. I checked the output of `systemd-analyze` this time and it said: `Startup finished in 1min 33.676s (firmware) + 4.203s (loader) + 3.647s (kernel) + 25.486s (userspace) = 2min 7.014s` although I don't feel I had to wait 2 minutes, it was ~1 min.

Comment: Disable those fsck services, you can always re-enable them. In a command prompt 'sudo systemctl disable <something.service>' then to stop it running again on boot 'sudo systemctl mask <something.service>'. Off course, you will need to put in your real service names eg 'systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-feee34bb\x2df3a8\x2d4ce6\x2d93d5\x2df22a01f95edf.service'.

Comment: I just timed (with the changes you proposed to `/etc/fstab`) it and it was 35 seconds to get to login screen from the grub menu (this time `systemd-analyze` gives 35 seconds too). Then, 12 seconds until everything appears in the desktop. If I want to open firefox it will take another 3-5 seconds giving ~ 50 seconds. I feel my old desktop with a quite old HDD does better, I will time it once I'm home.

Comment: OK, so faster then ? For info, Arch and red Hat web sites are particularly good for documentation. Here is a page on systemd you might find useful.    https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd.html

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is on the old laptop ? What version of firefox ? What kernel ? What is the hardware spec ?

Comment: I timed it at home and it took ~ 45 seconds to get to a working desktop, with an Intel Core 2 Duo 2.66 GHz x 2, 4 GB of RAM, and a 300 GB HDD with less than 1/3 in use and 1/2 unallocated. So it takes more or less the same time to boot with hardware from 1 year ago and with hardware from 8 years, and that's why it bothers me. Could it be because of the higher HDD size and allocated space of the HDD in the laptop? By the way, removing the fsck may have made a little difference although in the `systemd-analyze blame` output other services took the place of the fsck

Comment: What makes you think it should boot faster on different hardware ? Not trying to be pedantic here, I am trying to be helpfull, but I think you really are going down a rabbit hole here. 45 seconds seems fine from my point of view, it's hardly a long time. Can I ask why it is so critical that it boots faster ? If you really do want to see a speed increase, install an SSD. Lightning fast.

Comment: I think I should see an improvement when using better hardware but I feel it is a slow boot (and I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a modern friend's laptop who is not used to non-windows OS, she noticed it too and told me that booting with windows was not that slow...).  Furthermore, when shutting down at home it happens almost instantly while with the laptop it can take 30 seconds. There is a problem with a timeout when shutting down that sais "There is a stopping job for a crash report daemon" I already disabled some services because I had more timeouts, but maybe this is related to boot.

Comment: I think your windows might be doing a fast resume. It is a great feature, no reason why you wouldn't be using it.  As a test, disable fast resume in Windows and shut down the PC completely. No suspend, no hibernate, no hybrid sleep. Do a real power on from cold and see how long it takes.